# Preventing pronoun confusion

Tags: pronouns, word-order, ambiguity, phrase-order

I have two people. Fred knows something about X. Jim is curious how much Fred knows. Fred has also made some wrong assumptions about X.

In describing the scene, I wrote this:

> Perhaps Fred didn't know as much as Jim hoped he knew, and had made some wrong
>   assumptions.

Then I thought about whether the pronouns and ordering had made it ambiguous. In the sentence, is it clear that hopes are Jim's, but they are hopes about Fred's knowledge; and is it clear that the wrong assumptions are (a) part of the "perhaps", and (b) belong to Fred?

In trying to re-write it to make it less ambiguous, I lose some of the flow.

Comment: I'd suggest: "Perhaps Fred didn't know as much as Jim had hoped he knew; Fred had made some wrong assumptions."

Comment: @rajah9 OK. And does the "he knew" refer back to Fred, even though it immediately follows "Jim" ?

Comment: Your sentence reads like this: *Perhaps Fred didn't know as much as Jim hoped Fred knew, and Fred had made some wrong assumptions.* You should omit the comma in your version: *Perhaps Fred didn't know as much as Jim hoped he knew and had made some wrong assumptions.* You could just leave out *he knew*: *Perhaps Fred didn't know as much as Jim hoped and had made some wrong assumptions.*

Comment: @TinfoilHat  I like your answer.  If you post as an answer, I'd accept.

Comment: I think the original is readily understandable by most native English readers.

Comment: The only possible "ambiguity" I can see is that *in a highly contrived context*, it might be we're talking about how much Jim hoped ***he himself*** knew, rather than how much he hoped Fred knew. The clause after the comma (which comma is irrelevant to the parsing) can only refer to the possibility of ***Fred*** making incorrect assumptions - it's not syntactically credible for anything in that clause to reference Jim.

Comment: @FumbleFingers This would make an excellent answer, especially if fleshed out about how the parts are parsed.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: There is no clause after the comma. So the comma marks what follows as nonessential: *Perhaps Fred didn't know diddly-squat (and [by the way] had [also] made some wrong assumptions).* For *perhaps* to apply to the whole situation, the comma needs to be removed: *Perhaps: Fred didn't know diddly-squat and had [therefore] made some wrong assumptions.*

Comment: @TinfoilHat: I'd say it's just a case of "deletion of predictably repeated text", from an underlying *Perhaps Fred didn't know as much as Jim hoped he knew, and **perhaps Fred** had made some wrong assumptions.*

Comment: FF's first comments form the answer you need. It beats me why such answers are posted as comments. I honestly think that giving the OPs the possibility to accept the best answers would give more credibility to this site. So, please, @FumbleFingers, do us the favour... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sentence reads like this:

> *Perhaps Fred didn't know as much as Jim hoped Fred knew, and Fred had made some wrong assumptions.*

You should omit the comma in your version:

> *Perhaps Fred didn't know as much as Jim hoped he knew and had made some wrong assumptions.*

If the pronoun still bothers you, you could leave out *he knew*:

> *Perhaps Fred didn't know as much as Jim hoped and had made some wrong assumptions.*

Comment: As I need to select an answer from those offered, I would love to know from the downvoter why he/she downvoted.